Tasker: Ping notification on shared calender new event
I'm trying to get a profile that triggers whenever my samsung calendar app detects a new event has been added to a shared calendar. The shared cal is an icloud calendar that is being synced by the 'Sync for icloud' app. I expect this app just periodically updates the CalDev calendar feed to my samsung calendar app, so the task would need to detect when this happens, compare the old calendar to the new one and then notify me of the changes. I could write this in C but I have no experience writing in tasker.
Ideally it would ping a notification of the event title and description.
I'm very new to tasker so am completely in the dark about how to set this up. Any help appreciated.
Thanks
